# Query database on clicking a link

Tags: php, anchor

I'm retrieving products from my database and listing them in a while loop. Like this

```
<?php
  while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    echo '<div class="product_info">';
     echo '<div class="category_product_title"><a href="category-page.php">Product</a>';
     echo '</div>';
      echo '<div   class="category_product_number">#'.$row[0].'('.$row[1].')'.'</div>';//prints id and name
     echo '<div class="category_product_description">'.$row[2].'</div>';//prints description
     echo '<div class="category_product_price">'.$row[4].'TL</div>';//prints price
      echo '<div class="category_details"><a href="productpage2.php">DETAILS</a></div>';//The link to   list the product details
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
 }
?>
```

I want to be able to print more details on a paticular prodcut when the "DETAILS" link is clicked by getting the id or name of that paticular product and using to query the database. 
I tried saving the id in a session variable like this `$_SESSION['id'] = $row[0]` but since i'm looping through these products, i'm not able to get the id of a specific product when it is clicked. How can i do this?. I'm confused because of the loop. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a different link to each one of the products with a `GET` variable.
Instead of `<a href="productpage2.php">DETAILS</a>`, the link could point to `<a href="productpage2.php?id='.$row[0].'">DETAILS</a>`.

Then, on the product page `productpage2.php`, you can get the selected ID from the `$_GET` superglobal array like this:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: this is probably better than my answer for this case. so used to doing this kind of thing with ajax.

Comment: Thanks. i thought of this but wasn't sure if it'll keep the id for a particular because of the loop. But it works fine apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this. I would probably do something like:

```
echo '<div class="product_info" data-product-number="' . $row[0] . '">';
```

Then just grab the `data-product-number` attribute with JavaScript and pass it along with the request. Obviously, you'll need to verify this on the server side somehow once the request is made, since a user could set the product number in the request to anything they'd like.